# Why do I only get a single image in table row?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to put 2 (or several) images side by side on a row.
But with code below I only get 1 image - why?

```
        var existingbody = document.getElementById('PulseBody');
        var newBody = document.createElement('tbody');
       var row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.style.height = "20px";
        row.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
        row.style.display = "table";

        var greenLight = document.createElement("img");
        greenLight.src = myPath + "/Images/GreenSquare.jpg";
        greenLight.style.height = "30px";
        greenLight.style.width = "30px";

        var cellImg = document.createElement('td');
        cellImg.appendChild(greenLight);
        row.appendChild(cellImg);

        var cellImg2 = document.createElement('td');
        cellImg2.appendChild(greenLight);
        row.appendChild(cellImg2);

        newBody.appendChild(row);

        existingbody.innerHTML = newBody.innerHTML;
```

Comment: `row.style.display = "table";` is very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the `element.style.*` rows and set that functionality in CSS.

But most importantly remove `row.style.display = "table"` - table rows will by default use a display of `table-row`. This shouldn't need to be set to anything else unless you're intentionally trying to break the default layout of a table.

Comment: Neither helps with getting 2 images side-by-side

Answer (score 0):

try this one using boostrap its very easy

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-2 " style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <img src="~/Content/FeedBack/Smile.png" alt="Mountain View" height="50" width="50" />                            
                        </div>



                        <div class="col-md-2" style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <img src="~/Content/FeedBack/Smile.png" alt="Mountain View" height="50" width="50" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 " style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <img src="~/Content/FeedBack/Smile.png" alt="Mountain View" height="50" width="50" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2" style="cursor: pointer;">                           
                            <img src="~/Content/FeedBack/Smile.png" alt="Mountain View" height="50" width="50" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

After that you can use javascript code to loop and add url for Image tag